# C++ fstream searching through a .txt for a structure

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

I have a program that allows the user to enter a new record (put into a structure then written to the file), print all records, or edit a specific record. I have included my function. The records are for a girlscout cookie info. It has the name, quantity, price, and cost. It opens the file asks the user to enter the name and then when it finds that name it has all the data read into a temporary structure variable (the same as what wrote it to the file) where the user can than just change the quantity and rewrite it in the same place it was read from. Everything should be the same except for the updated quantity.It does all of that but for some reason turns all the other records before it to null or 0's. What is my mistake that makes this change all my other records in the file. I just want to edit this specific one.
 This is just the function. Help would really be appreciated!

function code:

```
void editField()
{
    char input[20];
    fstream data("cookies.txt", ios::in);
    cookies test;

    if ( !data ) {
        cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting.\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "Please enter the name of the cookie you are searching for: ";
    cin.getline(input,20);

    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&test),
    sizeof(test));

    while (!data.eof())
    {
        if( strcmp(input,test.name) == 0 ) {

            int position = data.tellp();
            data.close();
            data.clear();
            data.open("cookies.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);

            cout << "Please enter the new quantity for the cookie ";
            cin >> test.quantity;

            data.seekp(position-sizeof(test),ios::cur);
            data.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&test), sizeof(test));
        }
        // Read the next record from the file.
        data.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&test),
        sizeof(test));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: As usual 'while (!data.eof())' is wrong - I did not read past that (after doing that, this code is junk)

Comment: This code does not compile as-is. Please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has the problem

Comment: This doesn't compile? I am running it right now as is? My includes are  #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

Comment: This code cannot be copied and pasted into a blank file and compiled. Something that are missing: main(), implementation of cookies, #includes for standard library functions being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change `while(!data.eof())` to `while(data)`
- For clarity, read a record from the file at the beginning of your `while` loop, not at the end.
- You can break out of the loop when your record has been written.
- When writing cookies.txt, open it with `std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out`. Seek from `std::ios::beg`.
- You have the file open for both reading and writing at the same time. This should work, but is unnecessary. Close the file for reading before writing to it.

Comment: Thank you! It was creating a new file by default when just in ios::out. Something that I should have already known. Thank you for being respectful and helpful to a newbie!